# debian prompt is broken

Tags: ssh, debian, bash, prompt

When I login via ssh or from the console this is what I see:

```
Linux sensu.lbox.com 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1 x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Fri Sep 27 12:40:33 2013
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
root@sensu:~#
```

What is this and how do I get rid of it?

```
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
```

I am unable to most commands and it says `command not found instead`

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is pretty far off-topic for server fault.  I'd suggest superuser or unix & linux.  To get you started: your startup files for bash (.bash_profile, .bashrc, et al.) have syntax issues.  Your path is not being set properly as well (likely due to above problem).

Comment: Sounds like you've somehow broken your entire system. What did you do?

Comment: Are all your filesystems mounted?  Your syste appears to be pretty broken.  What happens when you run `/bin/ls -al /usr/bin/id`?  Hopefully you see something like `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 31232 Nov 19  2012 /usr/bin/id`?  Have you changed your path?  Have you recently performed a recursive chown/chmod?  Is a HD failing?

Comment: Thanks guys! I had edited my /etc/environment file incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being caused by a bad /etc/environment file.

Comment: Remember to click the check mark so that this question is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen for all users or just root?  If it's everyone, try looking under /etc/profile.d for a script that was modified recently (since the problem started happening).. You could do `find /etc/ -path *profile* -mtime -5`  for something modified in the last 5 days.  If it is just for root, try looking at /root/.bashrc first for some bad scripting.

Comment: Thanks! I had edited my /etc/environment file incorrectly.